# 그렇지만 공부하는 걸/건/ 싫어해요/싫어요

Tags: grammar, meaning

1. 글을 쓰는 건 좋아해요. 그렇지만 공부하는 건 싫어해요.

What's the difference in meaning and nuance among the original sentence 1 and sentences 2,3?

2. 글을 쓰는 건 좋아해요. 그렇지만 공부하는 걸 싫어해요.
3. 글을 쓰는 건 좋아해요. 그렇지만 공부하는 건 싫어요.

Comment: If the subject is "I", there will be no recognizable differences in meaning. Because of 그렇지만 as well as 건, it is obvious that those sentences are all contrasting the two things.

Answer (score 1):

sentence 1 and sentence 3 mean the same

In this context, sentence 2 is not natural because '그렇지만' implies that the second sentence will contrast the first sentence.

So, to contrast the first sentence in a natural manner, you would say 공부 하는 '건' since you said 글을 쓰는 '건'

Case when you would say '걸':

그 사람은 누가 뒷담화하는걸 싫어해요

That person does not like when someone talks behind (someone's) back

Comment: Err, I think a space must precede the '걸'?